# Ember JS : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of null

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've started to develop an ember JS app using ember cli. 
For now the idea would be to create svg  elements (circles) by keeping the coordinates of a click.

I used a view to capture a mouse click and then pass it to a controller to create the circle with the coordinates. 
I'm using the fixture adapter to store datas.

The elements I've put manually in the code work fine when I display them.
The problem happens when I want to store a new node with my controller, I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of null
```

Here is the controller file svg.js :

```js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions:{
        createNode: function(posX,posY){
            var element= this.store.createRecord('element',{ //Here is where I get the error
                text: "element",
                x: posX,
                y: posY,
                graph: 1
            });
            element.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my template file :

```js
{{#view svg}}
  {{#each item in model}}//For each graph
    {{#each item.elements}}// For each  
        <circle {{bind-attr cx=x}} {{bind-attr cy=y}} r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="yellow" />
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/view}}
```

The associated route :

```js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('graph');
    }
});
```

The view file :

```js
export default Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: "svg",
    attributeBindings: ['width','height'],
    width: "500",
    height: "500",

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set("controller", svg.create());
    },
    click: function(evt){

        var svg= Ember.$("svg:first");
        var posX = evt.pageX - svg.position().left;
        var posY = evt.pageY - svg.position().top;
        this.get('controller').send('createNode',posX,posY);
    }
});
```

Maybe I've done something wrong but I don't know why `this.store` would be null.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the store works in other places, like when you get graphs, correct?

Comment: Yes that's right, there is no problem to get the graphs.

Comment: I tried to use another controller to create a record of an element with fixed coordinates and it works fine too. Clearly, I don't understand why a controller wouldn't have access to the store..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops, I didn't see what you were doing there in your init.  Controllers need to be initialized by the container in order to have dependency injection work with them.  Dependency injection injects the store into controllers and routes.

With controllers being deprecated in 2.0 I'd just say move your action from your controller into route/controller that's housing that view. You'd also have to pass the store into the view If you don't want to do that, you can manually define the store on the controller when you're creating it.

#### Define it on the view

```
{{#view svg store=store}}
```

#### Inject into the view, create an injector and add this

```
App.inject('view', 'store', 'store:main');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But actually, if I move my action in the view I get the same error where the property createrecord  can't be read. I really don't get it because like I said I used another controller with an action on my template and it works fine with creating records in the store.. How do you define your store manually in your view or controller? I've just begun to work on ember..